# I have a problem with os module in python

Tags: python, twitter, operating-system, python-twitter

I've recently had a problem with (i think) the os module in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    api = getApi(os.environ['consumer_key'], os.environ['consumer_secret'], os.environ['access_token_key'], os.environ['access_token_secret'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'consumer_key'
```

my code of `main.py` is:

```
from config import getApi
import os
import sys
import time
print()



api = getApi(os.environ['consumer_key'], os.environ['consumer_secret'], os.environ['access_token_key'], os.environ['access_token_secret'])
```

my code of `config.py` is

```
import twitter
import os

def getApi(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret):
    return twitter.Api(consumer_key='*********',
        consumer_secret='*********',
        access_token_key='*********',
        access_token_secret='*********')
```

Send tweets with the postUpdate is possible if I write the keys in the main.py but when I put the keys in the config.py, it don't works

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error with the `os` module, the keys simply aren't in the enviroment. If you're using a `.env` file you should use a module like [`dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to load the file.

Comment: I use a python file, how to include it ?

Comment: no, idk how i can import fct of another file

Comment: you do, you did it in the first example